# DataGrid with small rows and no data after binding to the ItemSource with LINQ query

Tags: sql, wpf, linq, xaml

I'm new to LINQ and WPF and I'm trying to bind a custom query from LINQ and the rows barely appear although when debugging the `IEnumerable<OrderSummary> orderSummary` has info in it.  I believe the empty rows showing are the amount of rows returned from the query:

[image]

XAML:

```
<DataGrid  Name="dgrOrders" Margin="59,54,161,285" />
```

Code Behind:

```
OrderITDataClassesDataContext dc = new OrderITDataClassesDataContext();
IEnumerable<OrderSummary> orderSummary = dc.ExecuteQuery<OrderSummary>("SELECT * FROM [Order]",1);
dgrOrders.ItemsSource = orderSummary;

public class OrderSummary
{
    int OrderId { get; set; }
    DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    int CustomerId { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: you said that you want to bind to that collection... then why are you setting datagrid's itemsSource in codebehind?

Comment: I took out the additional Binding (edited above), but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should use properties instead of fields. Check the examples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx)

```
public class OrderSummary
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

The second thing you may try - specify the dgrOrders `DataContext`, not the `ItemSource`.

Comment: Same thing after making {get;set;}  

DataContext made the rows disappear completely.

Comment: you should modify your answer a little. Make it more clear. Link is not an answer... you should cover all crucial parts in your answer. If he want's to bind to that collection then you are right that he should set that collection as datagrid's datacontext (with binding like this). But also he can set the itemssource as he did. From the picture it looks like his itemssource is set, but as you said... also not wery clear... members he wants to be displayed in datagrid should be properties... but you didn't mention that those properties  have to be public.

Comment: The properties in OrderSummary had to be set to public.  Thanks!